# Got banned from asking questions, but earned a lot of reputation. Can the ban be undone?

Tags: support, post-ban

I recently got banned from SO, I think it was because I had deleted a few questions that once after I posted, I realised they may not actually be that helpful to the community.

Since the ban I have earned over 30 rep from answers on SO.

I was just wondering is there a way to overturn the ban? As I cannot do anything with the deleted questions if that is the reason.

Comment: Your Stack Overflow account is not showing up as being banned; http://stackoverflow.com/users/993346/matt. What's the error message you're seeing? Do you mean http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi instead?

Comment: Two users called Matt? This is gonna be interesting. Original poster Mat, did you get any error messages? "Sorry we are no longer accepting..." or something else?

Comment: Yes sorry, i ment being banned from asking questions. The error message i get is "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?" - (Question Title Updated)

Comment: @Matt: In which case you should see the link I included in my comment; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi

Comment: @Matt I have read through that link before, I have earned a fair bit of reputation and upvotes but still nothing, think it may be to do with deleted questions? How can i fix this?

Comment: 30 rep on answers is only 3 upvotes. I suspect you'll have to earn a bit more than that.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't thank anybody in your questions?Because it is not welcomed very much.

Comment: @OkayGuy: It's not necessarily encouraged, but I hardly think it would get someone banned.

Comment: Good news, I seem to now be able to post questions again :) Ill remember to give back to the community now and keep my questions relevent.

Comment: @KeithThompson I got banned because I rolled back edits which removed my "Thank you" at the bottom of my question Keith.

Comment: @Matt good luck Matt.

Comment: Don't delete a bunch of your questions.  I undeleted a few; either rewrite them to improve or just let them sit until you get more rep and can delete without worrying about triggering the autoban.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this post with all of the official information about question bans:

### [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-thi)

For what it's worth, 30 rep is not "a lot", but it's a good start. If you continue providing good answers and earning reputation, it's possible to re-earn the privilege to ask questions, but is not guaranteed.